# To have one color bar placed on the blank space

Tags: python

I've spent entirely too long researching how to get subplots to share the same  single colorbar.

I have a ERA5 hourly datasets and want to create a monthly mean using python for summer months from September to April. These should have a single color bar. The following code is doing this manual using to months but i am failing to make the subplots share a colorbar.

Here is my code:

```
        ib = 3
        jb = 3
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,15))
        ax=plt.subplot(331, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
        levels =  np.arange(0,100)
        ax.add_feature(cf.COASTLINE, alpha=0.5)
        ax.add_feature(cf.BORDERS, alpha=0.5, linestyle='--')
        
        xticks =np.arange(8,56,8)
        ax.set_xticks(xticks)
        ax.set_xlim([8,50])
        yticks = np.arange(-50,0,10)
        ax.set_yticks(yticks)
        ax.set_ylim([-50,-10])
        
        chandles0=ax.contourf(lons,lats,np.squeeze(shum_month[shum_month.month==9]),cmap = 'magma_r')
        ax.set_title('(a) Sep')
        plt.colorbar(chandles0, orientation = 'vertical', label =r'850-hPa Specific Humidity $(g {kg}^{-1})$')
        ax=plt.subplot(332, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
        chandles0=ax.contourf(lons,lats,np.squeeze(shum_month[cape_month.month==10]),cmap = 'magma_r')
        ax.add_feature(cf.COASTLINE, alpha=0.5)
        ax.add_feature(cf.BORDERS, alpha=0.5, linestyle='--')
        xticks =np.arange(8,56,8)
        ax.set_xticks(xticks)
        ax.set_xlim([8,50])
        yticks = np.arange(-50,0,10)
        ax.set_yticks(yticks)
        ax.set_ylim([-50,-10])
        
        ax.set_title('(b) Oct')
        plt.colorbar(chandles0, orientation = 'vertical', label =r'850-hPa Specific Humidity $(g {kg}^{-1})$')
        ax=plt.subplot(333, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
        ax.contourf(lons,lats,np.squeeze(cape_month[cape_month.month==11]),cmap = 'magma_r')
        ax.add_feature(cf.COASTLINE, alpha=0.5)
        ax.add_feature(cf.BORDERS, alpha=0.5, linestyle='--')
        xticks =np.arange(8,56,8)
        ax.set_xticks(xticks)
        ax.set_xlim([8,50])
        yticks = np.arange(-50,0,10)
        ax.set_yticks(yticks)
        ax.set_ylim([-50,-10])
        

        fig.savefig('shum_850hPa.jpg', dpi = 1000)
```

Comment: Would you please [edit] your question and add a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The way it is is hard to tell which imports you have

Comment: @Lepsch, Actually I have a ERA5 hourly datasets and want to create a monthly mean using python for summer months from September to April. These should have a single color bar. The code i above is able to do monthly manual but i am failing to make the subplots share a colorbar.

Comment: Try to create a small complete example and copy-paste it into the question itself. It'll help a lot to find out what's going on. Just [edit] your question with it.